# Undo a file readline() operation so file-pointer is back in original state

Tags: python, file-io, readline, readlines

I'm browsing through a Python file pointer of a text file in read-only mode using file.readline() looking for a special line.  Once I find that line I want to pass the file pointer to a method that is expecting the file pointer to be at the START of that readline (not right after it.)

How do I essentially undo one file.readline() operation on a file pointer?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You have to remember the position by calling `file.tell()` before the readline and then calling `file.seek()` to rewind.  Something like:

```
fp = open('myfile')
last_pos = fp.tell()
line = fp.readline()
while line != '':
  if line == 'SPECIAL':
    fp.seek(last_pos)
    other_function(fp)
    break
  last_pos = fp.tell()
  line = fp.readline()
```

I can't recall if it is safe to call `file.seek()` inside of a `for line in file` loop so I usually just write out the `while` loop.  There is probably a much more pythonic way of doing this.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be safe to call in a for line in file loop.  "OSError: telling position disabled by next() call"

Comment: @Jiminion: Yeah, you have to use `.readline()` (which is slightly less efficient, but preserves necessary positional information) for that to work. You can still write a loop over lines pretty easily though, either with the walrus in more modern Python, `while line := fp.readline():`, or with two-arg `iter` (on any version) `for line in iter(fp.readline, ''):` (change `''` to `b''` if the file is opened in binary mode).

Answer (score 15):

You record the starting point of the line with `thefile.tell()` before you call `readline`, and get back to that point, if you need to, with `thefile.seek`.

```
>>> with open('bah.txt', 'w') as f:
...   f.writelines('Hello %s\n' % i for i in range(5))
... 
>>> with open('bah.txt') as f:
...   f.readline()
...   x = f.tell()
...   f.readline()
...   f.seek(x)
...   f.readline()
... 
'Hello 0\n'
'Hello 1\n'
'Hello 1\n'
>>>
```

as you see, the seek/tell "pair" is "undoing", so to speak, the file pointer movement performed by `readline`.  Of course, this can only work on an actual seekable (i.e., disk) file, not (e.g.) on file-like objects built w/the makefile method of sockets, etc etc.

Answer (score 6):

If your method simply wants to iterate through the file, then you could use `itertools.chain` to make an appropriate iterator:

```
import itertools

# do something to the marker line and everything after
def process(it):
    for line in it:
        print line,
        
with open(filename,'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if 'marker' in line:
            it=itertools.chain((line,),f)
            process(it)
            break
```

Answer (score 1):

```
fin = open('myfile')
for l in fin:
    if l == 'myspecialline':
        # Move the pointer back to the beginning of this line
        fin.seek(fin.tell() - len(l))
        break
# now fin points to the start of your special line
```

Comment: I'm thinking along the same lines as you, but the file.seek help suggests otherwise: `If the file is opened in text mode, only offsets returned by tell() are legal.`

Comment: I've used this before a few times and haven't had any problems, I'm assuming his has something to do with other character encodings

Comment: in text mode, `\r\n` is going to translate to `\n` so you will lose a character.  In this case, that character would be the CR (`\r`) so no one notices ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the last line because you didn't visit it you can read backwards until you see a newline character:

```
with open(logfile, 'r') as f:
    # go to EOF
    f.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)
    nlines = f.tell()
    i=0
    while True:
        f.seek(nlines-i)
        char = f.read(1)
        if char=='\n':
            break
        i+=1
```