# Python: rewinding one line in file when iterating with f.next()

Tags: python, iterator, seek

Python's f.tell doesn't work as I expected when you iterate over a file with f.next():

```
>>> f=open(".bash_profile", "r")
>>> f.tell()
0
>>> f.next()
"alias rm='rm -i'\n"
>>> f.tell()
397
>>> f.next()
"alias cp='cp -i'\n"
>>> f.tell()
397
>>> f.next()
"alias mv='mv -i'\n"
>>> f.tell()
397
```

Looks like it gives you the position of the buffer rather than the position of what you just got with next().

I've previously used the seek/tell [trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505479/python-undo-a-python-file-readline-operation-so-file-pointer-is-back-in-origin) to rewind one line when iterating over a file with readline().  Is there a way to rewind one line when using next()?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No.  I would make an adapter that largely forwarded all calls, but kept a copy of the last line when you did `next` and then let you call a different method to make that line pop out again.

I would actually make the adapter be an adapter that could wrap any iterable instead of a wrapper for file because that sounds like it would be frequently useful in other contexts.

Alex's suggestion of using the `itertools.tee` adapter also works, but I think writing your own iterator adapter to handle this case in general would be cleaner.

Here is an example:

```
class rewindable_iterator(object):
    not_started = object()

    def __init__(self, iterator):
        self._iter = iter(iterator)
        self._use_save = False
        self._save = self.not_started

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def next(self):
        if self._use_save:
            self._use_save = False
        else:
            self._save = self._iter.next()
        return self._save

    def backup(self):
        if self._use_save:
            raise RuntimeError("Tried to backup more than one step.")
        elif self._save is self.not_started:
            raise RuntimeError("Can't backup past the beginning.")
        self._use_save = True


fiter = rewindable_iterator(file('file.txt', 'r'))
for line in fiter:
    result = process_line(line)
    if result is DoOver:
        fiter.backup()
```

This wouldn't be too hard to extend into something that allowed you to backup by more than just one value.

Comment: This is the best solution for me.  I already had something like a wrapper so it was easy to modify it this way.

Comment: Update for python3: use `__next__` in place of next and this example will work out. See http://getpython3.com/diveintopython3/porting-code-to-python-3-with-2to3.html#next

Answer (score 5):

[itertools.tee](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee) is probably the least-bad approach -- you can't "defeat" the buffering done by iterating on the file (nor would you want to: the performance effects would be terrible), so keeping two iterators, one "one step behind" the other, seems the soundest solution to me.

```
import itertools as it

with open('a.txt') as f:
  f1, f2 = it.tee(f)
  f2 = it.chain([None], f2)
  for thisline, prevline in it.izip(f1, f2):
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Python's file iterator does a lot of buffering, thereby advancing the position in the file far ahead of your iteration. If you want to use `file.tell()` you must do it "the old way":

```
with open(filename) as fileob:
  line = fileob.readline()
  while line:
    print fileob.tell()
    line = fileob.readline()
```