# What is the difference between the buffering argument to open() and the hardcoded readahead buffer size used when iterating through a file?

Tags: python, file-io, io-buffering

Inspired by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15979793/is-there-any-way-to-find-the-buffer-size-of-a-file-object), I'm wondering exactly what the optional buffering argument to Python's `open()` function does. From looking at [the source](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/84cd07899baf/Objects/fileobject.c), I see that `buffering` is passed into `setvbuf` to set the buffer size for the stream (and that it does nothing on a system without `setvbuf`, which the docs confirm).

However, when you iterate over a file, there is a constant called `READAHEAD_BUFSIZE` that appears to define how much data is read at a time (this constant is defined [here](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/84cd07899baf/Objects/fileobject.c#l2314)).

My question is exactly how the `buffering` argument relates to `READAHEAD_BUFSIZE`. When I iterate through a file, which one defines how much data is being read off disk at a time? And is there a place in the C source that makes this clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`READAHEAD_BUFSIZE` is *only* used when you use the file as an iterator:

```
for line in fileobj:
    print line
```

It is a separate buffer from the normal buffer argument, which is handled by the `fread` C API calls. Both are used when iterating.

From [`file.next()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.next):

> In order to make a `for` loop the most efficient way of looping over the lines of a file (a very common operation), the `next()` method uses a hidden read-ahead buffer. As a consequence of using a read-ahead buffer, combining `next()` with other file methods (like `readline()`) does not work right. However, using `seek()` to reposition the file to an absolute position will flush the read-ahead buffer.

The OS buffer size is not changed, the `setvbuf` is done when the file is opened and not touched by the file iteration code. Instead, calls to `Py_UniversalNewlineFread` (which uses `fread`) are used to fill the read-ahead buffer, creating a *second* buffer internal to Python. Python otherwise leaves the regular buffering up to the C API calls (`fread()` calls are buffered; the userspace buffer is consulted by `fread()` to satisfy the request, Python doesn't have to do anything about that).

`readahead_get_line_skip()` then serves lines (newline terminated) from this buffer. If the buffer no longer contains newlines, it'll refill the buffer by recursing over itself with a buffer size 1.25 times the previous value. This means that file iteration can read the whole rest of the file into the memory buffer if there are no more newline characters in the whole file!

To see how much the buffer reads, print the file position (using `fileobj.tell()`) while looping:

```
>>> with open('test.txt') as f:
...     for line in f:
...         print f.tell()
... 
8192   # 1 times the buffer size
8192
8192
~ lines elided
18432  # + 1.25 times the buffer size
18432
18432
~ lines elided
26624  # + 1 times the buffer size; the last newline must've aligned on the buffer boundary
26624
26624
~ lines elided
36864  # + 1.25 times the buffer size
36864
36864
```

etc.

What bytes are actually read from the disk (provided `fileobj` is an actual physical file on your disk) depend not only on the interplay between the `fread()` buffer and the internal read-ahead buffer; but also if the OS itself is using buffering. It could well be that even if the file buffer is exhausted, the OS serves the system call to read from the file from it's own cache instead of going to the physical disk.

Comment: But `setvbuf` is called when you call `open`. Presumably somewhere inside `file_iternext` an OS-level read is called, so this read overwrites the buffer size set with `setvbuf` in order to use `READAHEAD_BUFSIZE`?

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't understand. I'm looking at two functions, `file_iternext` and `file_read`. Both get data from the file by calling `Py_UniversalNewlineFread`, passing it `bufsize` equal to `READAHEAD_BUFSIZE` or the size of the file, respectively. `Py_UniversalNewlineFread` then reads `bufsize` bytes by calling `fread`. Maybe `fread` doesn't use the buffer set by `setvbuf`, but then I'm confused as to what the point of the `buffering` argument is: what file operations does it set the buffer size for?

Comment: I think I understand now; your answer was helpful but I didn't quite get from it how _both_ `buffering` and `READAHEAD_BUFSIZE` affect how many bytes are read while iterating. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

After digging through the source a bit more and trying to understand more how `setvbuf` and `fread` work, I think I understand how `buffering` and `READAHEAD_BUFSIZE` relate to each other: when iterating through a file, a buffer of `READAHEAD_BUFSIZE` is filled on each line, but filling this buffer uses calls to `fread`, each of which fills a buffer of `buffering` bytes.

Python's `read` is implemented as [file_read](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/84cd07899baf/Objects/fileobject.c#l1052), which calls [Py_UniversalNewlineFread](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/84cd07899baf/Objects/fileobject.c#l2809), passing it the number of bytes to read as `n`. `Py_UniversalNewlineFread` then eventually calls `fread` to read n bytes.

When you iterate over a file, the function [readahead_get_line_skip](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/84cd07899baf/Objects/fileobject.c#l2269) is what retrieves a line. This function also calls `Py_UniversalNewlineFread`, passing `n = READAHEAD_BUFSIZE`. So this eventually becomes a call to `fread` for `READAHEAD_BUFSIZE` bytes.

So now the question is, how many bytes does `fread` actually read from disk. If I run the following code in C, then 1024 bytes get copied into `buf` and 512 into `buf2`. (This might be obvious but never having used `setvbuf` before it was a useful experiment for me.)

```
FILE *f = fopen("test.txt", "r");
void *buf = malloc(1024);
void *buf2 = mallo(512);
setvbuf(f, buf, _IOFBF, 1024);
fread(buf2, 512, 1, f);
```

So, finally, this suggests to me that when iterating over a file, *at least* `READAHEAD_BUF_SIZE` bytes are read from disk, but it might be more. I think that the first iteration of `for line in f` will read x bytes, where x is the smallest multiple of `buffering` that is greater than `READAHEAD_BUF_SIZE`.

If anyone can confirm that this is what's actually going on, that would be great!