# Differences between write and tempfile.write

Tags: python, file

Please explain the following:

```
def feed(data):
  import os
  print "DATA LEN: %s" % len(data)
  f = open("copy", "w")
  f.write(data)
  f.close()
  print "FILE LEN: %s" % os.stat("copy").st_size
  t = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
  t.write(data)
  print "TEMP LEN: %s" % os.stat(t.name).st_size
  t.close()

feed(x)
DATA LEN: 11004
FILE LEN: 11004
TEMP LEN: 8192
```

Why the difference, and can I fix temp? The end seems to be chopped.

Tested on 2.6, 2.7

Comment: The only difference I can spot in the documentation seems to be, that on Windows you have to append a "b" to open, because windows distinguishes between binary and non-binary and tempfile automatically calls "w+b".

Comment: What happens if you `.flush()` (or `.close()` for that matter) before you `stat`?

Comment: Bingo! Thank you. .flush() solved the problem. .close() will delete the tempfile. If you care to elucidate I'll accept.

Comment: FWIW, [I've seen this magic number (8192) before ...](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15983708/748858)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're running into the internal write buffer size.  In the first case, you `.close()` the file before calling `os.stat` which effectively flushes the internal buffer.  In the second case (with the `tempfile`), you still have the file open when you call `os.stat`.  Since the file is still open, some of it may still be buffered in memory until you `flush` it explicitly or by closing it.