# set current position in a text file one line back

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I want to set the current position in a textfile one line back.

Example:

I search in a textfile for a word "x".

Textfile:

1. Line:  qwe qwe
2. Line:  x
3. Line:  qwer
4. Line:  qwefgdg

If i find that word, the current position of the fobj shall be set back one line. 
( in the example I find the word in the 2. Line so the position shall be set to the beginning of the 1. Line)

I try to use fseek. But I wasn't that succesfull.

Comment: This might help, [make a python iterator go backwards](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777188/making-a-python-iterator-go-backwards)

Comment: I did like here. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505479/python-undo-a-python-file-readline-operation-so-file-pointer-is-back-in-origi

Answer (score 2):

This is not how you do it in Python. You should just iterate over the file, test the current line and never worry about file pointers. If you need to retrieve the content of the previous line, just store it.

```
>>> with open('text.txt') as f: print(f.read())
a
b
c
d
e
f

>>> needle = 'c\n'

>>> with open('test.txt') as myfile:
    previous = None
    position = 0
    for line in myfile:
        if line == needle:
            print("Previous line is {}".format(repr(previous)))
            break
        position += len(line) if line else 0
        previous = line

Previous line is 'b\n'

>>> position
4
```

If you really need the byte position of the previous line, be aware that the `tell/seek` methods don't blend well with iteration, so reopen the file to be safe.

Answer (score 0):

```
f = open('filename').readlines()
i = 0
while True:
   if  i > range(len(f)-1):
       break
   if 'x' in f[i]:
      i = i - 1
   print f[i]
   i += 1
```

Be careful as that will create a forever loop. Make sure you enter an exit condition for loop to terminate.