# Is there a way to go back when reading a file using seek and calls to next()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator, seek, tell

I'm writing a Python script to read a file, and when I arrive at a section of the file, the final way to read those lines in the section depends on information that's given also in that section. So I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505479/python-undo-a-python-file-readline-operation-so-file-pointer-is-back-in-origi) that I could use something like

```
fp = open('myfile')
last_pos = fp.tell()
line = fp.readline()
while line != '':
  if line == 'SPECIAL':
  fp.seek(last_pos)
  other_function(fp)
  break
last_pos = fp.tell()
line = fp.readline()
```

Yet, the structure of my current code is something like the following:

```
fh = open(filename)

# get generator function and attach None at the end to stop iteration
items = itertools.chain(((lino,line) for lino, line in enumerate(fh, start=1)), (None,))
item = True

  lino, line = next(items)

  # handle special section
  if line.startswith['SPECIAL']:

    start = fh.tell()

    for i in range(specialLines):
      lino, eline = next(items)
      # etc. get the special data I need here

    # try to set the pointer to start to reread the special section  
    fh.seek(start)

    # then reread the special section
```

But this approach gives the following error:

> telling position disabled by next() call

Is there a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using the file as an iterator (such as calling `next()` on it or using it in a `for` loop) uses an internal buffer; the actual file read position is further along the file and using `.tell()` will not give you the position of the next line to yield.

If you need to seek back and forth, the solution is not to use `next()` directly on the file object but use `file.readline()` only. You can still use an iterator for that, use the two-argument version of `iter()`:

```
fileobj = open(filename)
fh = iter(fileobj.readline, '')
```

Calling `next()` on `fileiterator()` will invoke `fileobj.readline()` until that function returns an empty string. In effect, this creates a file iterator that *doesn't* use the internal buffer.

Demo:

```
>>> fh = open('example.txt')
>>> fhiter = iter(fh.readline, '')
>>> next(fhiter)
'foo spam eggs\n'
>>> fh.tell()
14
>>> fh.seek(0)
0
>>> next(fhiter)
'foo spam eggs\n'
```

Note that your `enumerate` chain can be simplified to:

```
items = itertools.chain(enumerate(fh, start=1), (None,))
```

although I am in the dark why you think a `(None,)` sentinel is needed here; `StopIteration` will still be raised, albeit one more `next()` call later.

To read `specialLines` count lines, use `itertools.islice()`:

```
for lino, eline in islice(items, specialLines):
    # etc. get the special data I need here
```

You can just loop directly over `fh` instead of using an infinite loop and `next()` calls here too:

```
with open(filename) as fh:
    enumerated = enumerate(iter(fileobj.readline, ''), start=1):
    for lino, line in enumerated:
        # handle special section
        if line.startswith['SPECIAL']:
            start = fh.tell()

            for lino, eline in islice(items, specialLines):
                # etc. get the special data I need here

            fh.seek(start)
```

but do note that your line numbers will still increment even when you seek back!

You probably want to refactor your code to not need to re-read sections of your file, however.

Comment: Thanks @Martijn. What happens with the enumerator call for getting the line number as well?

Comment: @AlejandroMarcosAragon: Your use of `chain()` there is a little.. weird, but it'll work.

Comment: I had to add None at the end, otherwise I had a `StopIteration` exception when I reached the end of the file.
I still can't make the `iter` take the enumerate for the lino.

Comment: @AlejandroMarcosAragon: You can ask `next()` to return `None` instead when you reach the end; `next(items, None)`. You appear to have an off-by-one error, as all you did is postpone the `StopIteration` by one more call.

Comment: Alright, this is what I have so far. I tried:
    `fit = enumerate(fh, start=1)
     try:
      while True:
        lino, line = next(fit, None)`

but this gives me a `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable`. So I enclosed the call to next in a try to break the loop. Can I improve it further?

Comment: I'm still getting the error `telling position disabled by next() call` making the changes and I'm now using an iterator.

Comment: @AlejandroMarcosAragon: make sure you are not calling `next()` on the actual file handle somewhere still, *only* use the `iter(fileobj.readline, '')` object to call `next()` on, and call `tell()` on the unwrapped file object.

Comment: In the input file, every line in the special section defines an object of certain type. So I need to know by the end of the special section, how many objects of which type I have in order to create a dictionary so that I can construct later numpy arrays of the right size.

Comment: @AlejandroMarcosAragon: Then why not track that in a counter somewhere, and / or store the objects parsed so far?

Comment: But isn't that more inefficient? A huge file can have millions of these lines.

Comment: It sounds as if you are *already* storing the information in memory somewhere.

Comment: I will do the test, I'll create a very big input file and I'll try to read it both ways to check the difference in speed and I'll let you know.

Comment: So I did the test with both cases, in the other case I use io.StringIO to write the file that I already read. I turns out the tell, seek approach is faster (1m16.911s compared to 1m28.933s for 3973781 of those lines).

Comment: I didn't mean for you to use an in-memory file object. It isn't clear to me why you need to parse the same section of text twice each time still.

Comment: I'll explain better. That section contains as many lines as elements (objects that need to be created). But information about these objects is stored in numpy arrays. The moment I start parsing the first time, I have no idea about how many types of different elements I have and how many elements for each type so I can't create the numpy arrays in advance. So by the end of the first pass, since I have this info, I am create the arrays. In the second pass I assign the data of the elements to the arrays.

Comment: @AlejandroMarcosAragon: and you cannot put the data you'll put in the arrays, into Python lists first?

Comment: I could, but would that be more efficient than what I did with a SringIO?

Comment: I don't know, I don't know your data.

Comment: Less looping, less I/O.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert with version 3 of Python, but it seems like you're reading using `generator` that `yields` lines that are read from file. Thus you can have only one-side direction.

You'll have to use another approach.