# Reading Words from a File and Writing Them on The Same Line

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a file that contains a word per a line. Each sentence is separated by an empty line. I want to read the file and write the whole words of a sentence on the same line. For example:

```
This 
is 
a
sample
input

Hello
World
!!
```

The desired output is:

```
This is a sample input
Hello World !!
```

I try this:

```
file = open('Words.txt', "r")
Writfile = open('Sent.txt','w')

for line in file:
    if line in ['\n']:
        Writfile.write('\n')
    else:
        Writfile.write(line + " ",)
```

Comment: possible double with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23598410/python-read-a-line-and-write-back-to-that-same-line ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: read a line and write back to that same line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23598410/python-read-a-line-and-write-back-to-that-same-line)

Comment: Also, please be more specific about the errors you are encountering with your attempted approach.

Comment: @MichaelOhlrogge, Simply, I did not get the desired format, I'm not sure what you are looking for by your comment!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try doing it this way:

```
with open("infile.txt", "r") as infile:
  string = infile.read().split("\n\n")

with open("outfile.txt", "w") as outfile:
  for s in string:
    outfile.write(s.replace("\n"," ") + "\n")
```

Output written on file:

```
This  is  a sample input
Hello World !!
```

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

```
input = """This
is
a
sample
input

Hello
World
!!
"""

import StringIO
fi = StringIO.StringIO(input)
lines = fi.read().split("\n")
one_line = " ".join(lines)
print one_line
```

will output:

`This is a sample input  Hello World !!`

The StringIO is there only to fake the reading of a file