# Edit specific line in a big file

Tags: python

I want to edit a a big file in specific lines.
So it isnt a good Idea to read the whole file before editing, thats why I dont
want to use:

```
myfile.readlines()
```

I have to read each line check if there a special content in it and then i have to edit this line.

So far Im reading every line:

```
file = open("file.txt","r+")
i = 0
for line in file:
    if line ......:
        //edit this line
        //this is where i need help


file.close()
```

So the Question is:
How can I edit the current line in the If Statement for example:
if the current line is "test" I want to replace it with "test2" and then write "test2" back into the file into the line where "test" was before

Comment: So..what is your ask ?

Comment: how can i edit the specific line in the if statement

Comment: line is going to be a str object, so just treat is as you would treat any str object..

Comment: ok and how can i write the edited string back in to the file at the same line as the one before was ?

Comment: I'd suggest you read this, http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/06/readlines-considered-silly.html

Comment: i think you didnt get my problem.... i know that i shouldnt use "readlines" thats why I'm not using it. My problem is to write the edited line back into the line where it was before i edited it.

Comment: OP isn't using readlines, but I like the recommended site.

Comment: Is the new line *exactly* the same length as the old line?  if not then just overwriting it will either leave old data or will overwrite part of the next line.

Comment: it is not exactly the same length

Comment: Ahhhh ok, sorry, well, lines in File are not organized by lines, so its extremely hard, so, the most efficient way is to save a new file with the new data, https://stackoverflow.com/a/23598472/1400926

Comment: ok thank you, so something like i did in my anwser ?

Comment: BASH to the rescue. Go here > https://stackoverflow.com/a/11145362/8726146

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will help

```
import fileinput

with fileinput.FileInput(filename, inplace=True, backup='.bak') as file:
    for line in file:
        print(line.replace(text_to_search, replacement_text), end='')
```

Answer (score 1):

The "if test" allows you to track the row you're looking for and its position at the same time—thanks to enumerate, which starts at 0 by default.

Then you can update your row—but before writing it, you need to change the stream position at the beginning of that row. That's what seek does.

In this example, each row has the same length and it counts bytes from (0, 0), then writes, and finally exits the loop, because you don't need further updates.

```
with open(filename, "r+") as file:
    for i, row in enumerate(file):
        if <your test>:
            # your update function
            row = update(row)
            file.seek(i * (len(row)+1))
            file.write(row)
            break
```

As long as the original and the modified row have the same length, you can proceed "in place". Otherwise, you 'll have to read the file, update your row, then write all again.

Something like :

```
with open(filename) as filein:
    rows = filein.readlines()

# your function to test and update the desired row
rows = update(rows)

with open(filename, "w") as fileout:
    fileout.writelines(rows)
```

If you don't want to use readlines, you can make a generator expression instead:

```
with open(filename) as filein:
    gen_rows = (
        update(row) if <your test> else row
        for row in filein
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

ok so as @EzzatA mentioned in the comments below the question it seems to be the best way to read the original file and create a new one with the edited data.
So something like this:

```
original_file = open("example.txt","r")
new_file = open("example_converted.xml","w")

string_tobe_replace = "test"
replacement_string = "test2"

for line in original_file:
    if string_tobe_replace in line:
        new_line = line.replace(string_tobe_replace,replacement_string)
        new_file.write(new_line)
    else:
        new_file.write(line)



original_file.close()
new_file.close()
```