# How to replace the first specific special character in each line by not touching the rest of that word in each of the line of a text file in python

Tags: python, string, replace, text-files

How to replace the first word in a series of occurrences like below.

Im trying to replace the first "/" in each line(if present) with a "", if not present, go to the next line in a text file.

ex: in.txt

```
Stackover flow /abc/one/two
is suitable to search three/four/five
answers for all /six/seven/eight
```

output like:

```
Stackover flow abc/one/two
is suitable to search three/four/five
answers for all six/seven/eight
```

I have tried re.sub with various combinations but not able to get any suitable answers.
I hope to find answers here .
Thanks in advance.

Comment: [`str.replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) has a *`count`* argument, use it.

Comment: To use "count" i need to have an exact number to use, but im trying to replace with variable text file sizes.

Comment: No, you use `1` to replace the first occurrence.

Comment: Please check the example again . I need to replace "/" every time it occurs first in the text file, not just once. I guess count =1 replaces only the first occurrence.

Comment: Yes, first occurrence on a line. Just read a file line by line and use that.

Comment: Ohh . umm no reading each with Readline() would mess up the syntax while writing back to the file and adds "\n" in each line.

Answer (score -1):

You can split the string with "/" and join again ignoring the first split.

```
split = _str.split("/")
_new_str = split[0]+"/".join(split[1:])
```

Answer (score -1):

If I understand the question correctly, you only try to change the first '/' when it's at the beginning of some list of options, e.g. '/abc/def/ghi', but not when it is between words, e.g. 'abc/def/ghi'.

This replaces '/' only if they are at the beginning of a word (per your example):

```
import re    

with open('in.txt', 'r') as input_file, open('out.txt', 'w') as output_file:
    for row in input_file:
        new_row = re.sub('\s/', ' ', row)
        output_file.write(new_row)
```

If you want to change the original file, I will refer you [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23598472/7195196) which is quite a nice explanation of why it is not a good idea.