# How to read a large file block by block and judge by block header?

Tags: python

I have a large file which I want to read block by block by matching the headers.
For example, the file is like this:

```
@header1
a b c 1 2 3
c d e 2 3 4
q w e 3 4 5


@header2
e 89 78 56
s 68 77 26
...
```

I wrote a script like this:

```
with open("filename") as f:
  line=f.readline()
  if line.split()[0]=="@header1":
     list1.append(f.readline().split()[0])
     list2.append(f.readline().split()[1])
     ...
  elif line.split()[0]=="@header2":
     list6.append(f.readline().split()[0])
     list7.append(f.readline().split()[1])
     ...
```

But it seems to only read the first header and did not read-in the second block. Also, there are some empty lines in between those blocks. How to read the block when the line matches certain strings and skip those empty lines.

I know in C, it would be switch. How to do the similar thing in python?

Comment: You need to add more details. Are these multiple space-seprated file-segments inside one file? Are the `@header...` guaranteed to be numbered sequentially and contiguously? If the `@header1` occurs all on its own, why do you test `line.split()[0]=="@header2"` rather than simply `line == "@header2"`? or just `line.startswith('@header')` , which should capture them all, and doesn't even need a regex ?

Comment: Ultimately I expect you want to read the space-separated rows contents (within each section, according to its header), so you'll want to wrap a reader object. Or write a generator to `yield` each chunk of rows separately, so you can then pass it into a reader object.

Comment: *"Also, there are some empty lines in between those blocks."* So, you're guaranteed that empty lines can only occur outside section, not inside them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO, your misconception is about how csv-files can be read. At least I doubt that ´switch´ from C would help here more than what can be done with if-clauses.

However, please understand, that you have to iterate through your file *line by line*. That is, there is nothing which can deal with whole blocks, if you do not know the length before.

So your algorithm is sth like:

for every line in the file:
. .is header?
. . .then prepare for this specific header
. .is empty line?
. . .then skip
. .is data?
. . .then append according to preparation above

In code this could be sth like

```
block_ctr = -1
block_data = []
with open(filename) as f:
    for line in f:                   
        if line:                         # test if line is not empty
            if line.startswith('@header'):
                block_ctr += 1
                block_data.append([])
            else:
                block_data[block_ctr].append(line.split())
```

Comment: It lends itself to a generator approach, see my answer

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you want to achieve exactly but maybe something like this:

```
with open(filename) as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('@'):
            print('header')
            # do something with header here
        else:
            print('regular line')
            # do something with the line here
```

Answer (score 0):

Attached at bottom is a solution using a Python generator `split_into_chunks(f)` to extract each section (as list-of-string), squelch empty lines, detect missing @headers and EOF. The generator approach is really neat because it allows you to further wrap e.g. a CSV reader object which handles space-separated value (e.g. pandas read_csv):

```
with open('your.ssv') as f:
    for chunk in split_into_chunks(f):
        # Do stuff on chunk. Presumably, wrap a reader e.g. pandas read_csv
        # print(chunk)
```

Code is below. I also parameterized the value `demarcator='@header'` for you. Note that we have to iterate with `line = inputstream.readline()`, `while line`, instead of the usual iterating with `for line in f`, since if we see the @header of the next section, we need to pushback with `seek/tell()` ; see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29618936/how-to-solve-oserror-telling-position-disabled-by-next-call) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505479/python-undo-a-python-file-readline-operation-so-file-pointer-is-back-in-origi) for explanation why. And if you want to modify the generator to yield the chunk header and body separately (e.g. as a list of two items), that's trivial.

```
def split_into_chunks(inputstream, demarcator='@header'):
    """Utility generator to get sections from file, demarcated by '@header'"""

    while True:
        chunk = []

        line = inputstream.readline()
        # At EOF?
        if not line: break
        # Expect that each chunk starts with one header line
        if not line.startswith(demarcator):
            raise RuntimeError(f"Bad chunk, missing {demarcator}")

        chunk.append(line.rstrip('\n'))

        # Can't use `for line in inputstream:` since we may need to pushback
        while line:
            # Remember our file-pointer position in case we need to pushback a header row
            last_pos = inputstream.tell()
            line = inputstream.readline()

            # Saw next chunk's header line? Pushback the header line, then yield the current chunk
            if line.startswith(demarcator):
                inputstream.seek(last_pos)
                break

            # Ignore blank or whitespace-only lines
            #line = line.rstrip('\n')
            if line:
                chunk.append(line.rstrip('\n'))

        yield chunk


with open('your.ssv') as f:
    for chunk in split_into_chunks(f):
        # Do stuff on chunk. Presumably, wrap it with a reader which handles space-sparated value, e.g. pandas read_csv
        print(chunk)
```

Answer (score 0):

I saw another post similar to this question and copied the idea here. I agree that SpghttCd is right although I have not tried that.

```
    with open(filename) as f:
        #find each line number that contains header
        for i,line in enumerate(f,1):
            if 'some_header' in line:
                index1=i
            elif 'another_header' in line:
                index2=i
            ...
    with open(filename) as f:
        #read the first block:
        for i in range(int(index1)):
            line=f.readline()
        for i in range('the block size'):
            'read, split and store'
        f.seek(0)
        #read the second block, third and ... 
        ...
```